# Centering a div inside a li

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<ul id="downmenu">
    <li class="copyright">
        <div>&copy; 2011. All rights reserved.</div>
    </li>
    <li class="twitter">
        <img src="images/twitter.png" alt="" />
    </li>
    <li class="facebook">
        <img src="images/facebook.png" alt="" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

And the following piece of CSS:

```
#downmenu {
    font-size:14px;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    clear: both;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 20px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 11px 0 11px 34px;
    width: 870px;   
}

#downmenu li {
    float:left;
}

#downmenu li.copyright {
    margin-right:540px;
    height:36px;
}

#downmenu li.copyright div{
    margin: auto 0;
}
```

(I think) `#downmenu li.copyright` is set to 36px tall, and I want to centre vertically the `div` inside it. To achieve that I've used `margin: auto 0;`. But it isn't centered.

Any clue?

Comment: Centering vertically is a bit tricky, take a look at this: http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the div altogether and use line-height to center your text.

Setting the line height equal to the height of the `li` will center it vertically.

```
    #downmenu li.copyright {
    margin-right:540px;
    height:36px;
    line-height:36px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#downmenu li.copyright {
    margin-right:540px;
    height:36px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I get the same.

Comment: Maybe try making the changing the `div` to an inline element like a `span`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to have line-height to be the same as the li height.

height: 36px;
line-height: 36px;

I see you have paddings, this might change how you see the div. Use something like Chrome Developer Console or firebug to see how your CSS is applied.